# Login from android to php server

Tags: php, android, authentication

I'm starting a new application that will have a server side PHP and client in Android another (at the moment, and then also probably iphone). The application will only be used from mobile customer applications ie not to be used by web. My question is what would be the best way to login to this mode of operation?

thank you very much

Comment: It depends on what your attempts are. What should this application do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me as if the server side will be some sort of API that opens up access to a users data. The easiest method would be sending along a stored username and password with each request. This would only work if the connection your using is secure (https) which brings in the hassle of obtaining an ssl certificate.

Another option would be using OAuth, though your use case seems a little bit different than the standard OAuth use-case. OAuth is a protocol that uses a token based system to establish a users permission to access certain data from an application by another application. In your case you would be in control of both the first and the second application (hence my remark on being different than the standard use-case) Read [here](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be more easier if you use a webservice to make this connection between android and php server 
this [Presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sullis/connecting-to-web-services-on-android) may help you ..

you are gonna deal with SOAP and xml or JSON to send data from android to php server.
and this a [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE&feature=plcp&context=C3b2c5c9UDOEgsToPDskL1TAx93frXRMV_sSC11yCm) that shows how to deal with REST android Apps. 
hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

I think building an API on the server-side would be the best approach. For example a simple [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) endpoint might be the way to go.

You can also host the API over HTTPS so that the communications channel is secure.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create PHP web service for that. and while accessing you can pass security key like IMEI of phone for log. I think it can be secured mode for login from Android Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice these days is to set up a simple JSON web service, and use the built in Android HTTP & JSON libraries to interact with this service.

Answer (score 0):

Create a login page in android, take the values from the fields send those values to server using httppost there store in your database and send response from the server

Answer (score 0):

i think you first make a login form on Php server and send it the login and password as soon as user types and php returns the JSON object then read it if login is accepted by server login to application.
another way is when user don't have the net access make some Content providers on android and store the user pass there and match from there locally.