# How to connect login details in android from laravel project?

Tags: android, laravel

how to use login in android by getting the login details in database from Laravel project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login from android to php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815773/login-from-android-to-php-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API (for example).

From your Android app, you make a request to your laravel project.

Comment: Should make clear a bit about how to create API, this was unclear for newbie.